# Button collapses when opening 2 identical tabs

Tags: extjs, tabs

I have a button called PrefixSearch. Now when i push this button it opens up a new tab, and in that tab there is another button:

```
onBtnPrefixSearchClick: function(button, e, options) {
    var newTab = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        title: 'Price Usage Report',
        autoScroll: true,
        layout: {
            type: 'fit'
        },
        closable: true,
        dockedItems: [
            {
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                dock: 'top',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        id: 'buttonBiding',
                        icon: 'images/dollar16x16.png',
                        text: 'button2',
                        listeners: {
                            click: {
                                fn: me.onBtnAddToBidClick,
                                scope: me
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]});
}
```

My problem is that if i push the PrefixSearch button twiced it opens up 2 tabs, and in the second tab that is open i cant push the inner button(button2), also when i try to close one of the tabs the all grid collapses.

I guess it has something to do to the fact the the 2 inner buttons has the same id maybe.

You can see the image here:

[image: buttoncollapses]

Comment: You're probably right, so don't give the same id to multiple components. It's forbidden both by Ext and the W3C (considering your id will end up as the id of an actual DOM element). Use [`itemId`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-cfg-itemId) instead. Flexible!

Comment: @rixo that's exactly what's going on.